# How could I start executables from within a modern browser?

Tags: security, web

I am responsible for our corporate application menu page (intranet only). It contains many links to resources (web pages and installed application) and is tailored to the current user.

In the past, I have used an applet to allow installed applications to be started directly from the browser.

The corporate web is going though a revamp and I have been told to find a solution which requires no plugins of any kind.

My first attempt was to register a custom protocol handler. The menu provider contains definitions for all the links and application commands and each user has different rights. I could imagine that, when the menu is created for a user, the commands could be encoded and added as something like `custom://base64encodedcommand`. The handler would decode the command, perform checks and execute it.

This works well in IE, FF and Chrome. At the moment, we have mainly Windows workstations and it will be used only within the company intranet.

Is this a viable approach? Are there security issues?

Comment: Yep - a malicious website could specify any command to be executed by the client machine simply by redirecting them to `custom://` + command. Don't rely on the fact that no one knows about this protocol. Always assume that any attacker is smarter than yourself.

Comment: @SilverlightFox - but what about the encoding? I'm using base64 during the test phase this could easily be upgraded to a different level of security. We were also considering a closed-loop where the menu provider adds a key which is checked before the command is executed. Just trying to figure out what is too much and what is too little....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with any solution it is possible to only prove the existance of a vulnerability, and never the lack there-of. But there are some necessery, but not sufficient ways to make your system more resistant to attacks.

Currently you are base64 encoding the execution string. This adds absolutely nothing to security. Even if you chose some different method, this will only be security through obscurity, and can easily be reverse engineered by somebody with enough time.

What you can do is to have some sort of public-private key signing set up. So that you can sign each link with your own private key, and that would mean that this link is allowed to be executed, a link without a signature or with an invalid signature should not even be decoded.

So what you would have is `custom://`+`base64link`+`separator`+`base64signature`.

Things to keep in mind:

1. It is very important that only you (or very select group of people) have access to private key. This is the same as with any other pub-priv key system.
2. Not only should you not run the link if the signature is invalid, but you must not even decode it (thus you sign the base64 string, not the decoded command). Assume that it is an attack right away, and probably even inform the user of the fact.

And i repeat, while this can be considered to be a necessary for security, it is not something that is sufficient. So keep thinking of other possible attacks.